# White specks on framing lumber

Tags: walls, wood, framing, lumber, new-home

I'm asking about advise\idea\help.
I'm new home buyer in Austin area TX.

I bought a new home in the foundation stage. Now it's in the framing stage.

I found that some lumbers (*about 4-5*) on the first floor have some strange white dots.

How I understand,  it's "white speck". Wood is solid.

**Should I be worried about this? Is it common\acceptable in the new construction?**

Video: https://youtu.be/FbykXVZIKgs

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's the consistency of the white material? Does it apparently fill in holes? Is this structural elements, or just studs? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Thank you, Deniel. Consistency  is solid but I can crack this white parts with a nail. It's part of the wall, so , seems. it's structural element. Technically I have 4-6 vertical lumbers. Sometimes holes are empty, sometimes I can see this white dots without holes. I'm adding stamp for these lumbers to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. If @isherwood's answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept.

Answer (score 2):

That's insect damage from when the tree was still in the forest. It's not really a problem now since the board has been cooked in a kiln. Any insects have leave the vicinity or been destroyed by heat. A few such boards are common with any unit of lumber, but if you see more than maybe 5% like that I'd be questioning whether your builder is buying from a reputable source.

That said, boards like that tend to be very soft and shouldn't be used in critical locations. They include wood that was probably dead at the time of harvest and is partially decomposed. For a common stud, not a concern. For a header or other specialty bit, it's to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you @Isherwood. This part will be under dry wall. So after some time it will be hided. Should I ask my builder to add some "insect killer" chemie to these parts? My builder doesn't see any issues with these lumbers.

Comment: As I said, it's already been baked in a kiln. No insects remain.

Answer (score 0):

As Isherwood said, the specks are insect damage.  Small amounts are not a problem, but more can be.  Another potential problem is that the pits are clustered more densely around a knot, and the knot it self is damaged.  I would remove such lumber from a load bearing location. Because of the wood structure around a knot, boards will often break at a knot.  The compromised material can fail, or deform, which can lead to deformation later. In a non-load bearing location it should not be a problem.